# Decoding base64 data in javascript, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, decoding

I'm facing a problem where I want to decode a base64 data I've got from a client.js.
If I put constant "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=" in the code, it's decoding fine to "Hello World".

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(Buffer.from("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=", 'base64').toString('ascii'));
});
```

But when I want to decode the data I got from my client it is not decoding, only writes me the base64 in the terminal (and it's all good, I get the right data from the client so that's not the problem).

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(Buffer.from(data, 'base64').toString('ascii'));
});
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: The problem could be the data is not a valid base64-encoded ASCII string. It could be UTF-8 encoded, then base64 encoded. Or any other encoding. If you were to provide an example of the encoded data that doesn't work, that would make it easier to answer, rather than speculate.

Comment: var text = 'Hello World';
var buff = new Buffer.from(text);
var base64data = buff.toString('base64');

This is the way I encode it.

Comment: Right, and that produces the string that you've shown works. But you're telling us that it doesn't work. Provide us with an example of a value for `data` that fails to provide the original string back, since that's what you say is the problem.

Comment: What @HereticMonkey is saying is "give us this: " : _data I got from my client it is not decoding_

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem, but anything is the `data`, it's not decoding it. For example I send the "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=" base64 from the client, I get it on my server, but it won't encode it if I use the `data` input variable from the function. But if i put it in a new variable, `var example = SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=;` and I put that in the code to decode it then it will do it fine. But if I make this variable: `var example = data;` it's not working either.

Comment: The funny thing is, if I write base64 in `.toString('base64'))` then it will decode the data again to base64, but if I try to decode it to anything else its not doing anything with it.

Comment: Try `console.log(typeof(data), data)` to see what type the data is(just to make sure it's a string) and to see the actual data. The output should be `string SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=`

Comment: This is what i got for the type and the data: object <Buffer 53 47 56 73 62 47 38 67 56 32 39 79 62 47 51 3d>

Comment: That's what i thought. So the data is actualy a buffer. Try `console.log(data.toString('utf8'))`

Comment: It's SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ= again

Comment: So `console.log(Buffer.from(data.toString('utf8'), 'base64').toString('ascii'));` should work

Comment: Wow, it's working, thank you very much :)